# nested jquery ui sortable: how to update indexes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a nested "list" of divs which should be reordered using jquery ui sortable.

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div>
        <span class="sortableIndex">1</span>
        <div class="sortable">
            <div>
                <span class="sortableIndex">1</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="sortableIndex">2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="sortableIndex">2</span>
        <div class="sortable">
            <div>
                <span class="sortableIndex">1</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="sortableIndex">2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript is quite simple:

```
$('.sortable').sortable();
```

Now I want to update the Numbers in the  elements according to their position when the divs are dragged. So I need some way to select the  elements without selecting the inner  elements. The  elements may be inside other elements so they may not be direct children of the dragged .

I am not very good at JS, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
It works by comparing the closest .sortable element to the .sortable element in which the dragged element is a direct children. If they match, I can update the number. If they do not match, they do not belong to the same level of the nested list.

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var self = ui.item;
        var p = self.parent('.sortable');
        var elems = p.find('.sortableindex');

        var order = 1;
        elems.each(function () {
            var elem = $(this);
            var closest = elem.closest('.sortable');
            if (closest[0] == p[0]) {
                elem.text(order);
                order++;
            }
        });
    }
});
```